# HTML Tooltip messes with how word breaks

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
Without tooltip:
<div>
(<span class="tt">Hoverable text in here</span>)
</div>

With tooltip:
<div>
(<span class="tt">Hoverable text in here<span class="ttt">random tooltip in here</span></span>)
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tt {
    position: relative;
  color: red;
}

.ttt {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.tt:hover .ttt {
    visibility: visible;
}

div {
  width: 150px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bf0arg1k/3/

It seems that html treats the parenthesis that come after the hidden span as if it is not attached to the last unhidden word.

I want the last parenthesis to stick to the last word. I could put the parenthesis inside of the span, but I want to have them be different colors.

I suppose I could put them inside the span and then put the parenthesis inside another span and apply css to them, but that seems like a pain.

Is there any better way of fixing this issue?

Comment: Add `white-space: nowrap` to the `.tt`

Comment: why not put tooltip at the beginning?

Comment: does rearranging like this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/js6w0qgb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `.ttt` outside the text span.

```css
.tt {
    position: relative;
  color: red;
}

.ttt {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
    margin-left: 25px;
  color:red;
}

.tt:hover ~ .ttt {
    visibility: visible;
}

div {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
Without tooltip:
<div>
(<span class="tt">Hoverable text in here</span>)
</div>

With tooltip:
<div>
(<span class="tt">Hoverable text in here</span>)
<span class="ttt">random tooltip in here</span>
</div>
```